# scrapy : allow is not defined when using Rule for link extraction

Tags: hyperlink, scrapy

```
rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow('.*?search_query=.*',), restrict_xpaths('ul[@class="paginator"]',)), callback='parse_item',allow=True),
```

NameError: name 'allow' is not defined

i am not able to detect any conclusion why this error is coming:
thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 2):

Without the rest of your spider code, it's a little tricky to test, but I noted the following:

1. There was a missing `=` sign after `allow`
2. After `callback='parse_item'`, the next part is `follow=True`, not `allow=True`
3. There was a missing `)` at the end of the statement
4. Have a read of the [scrapy CrawlSpider rules documentation](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules) for more information

Try the rules below, but if there is still an issue, then please post your full spider code so that I can test the rules statement. :)

```
rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.*?search_query=.*',), restrict_xpaths('ul[@class="paginator"]',)), 
        callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )
```